# Ambiguous use of "as well"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

I would appreciate it if a native speaker could answer to my question about the following conversation?

> A: Enjoy your holidays.
>   B: I hope you enjoy your time and be happy **as well**.

What does **as well** refer to? Does it relate the second part of response ("be happy" to the first part ("enjoy your time")? Or does it respond to the first friend's expression of good wishes ("I hope that for you, too")?

Answer (score 3):

In that context, the difference is so subtle that it really doesn't matter. The two people could have just said:

> Enjoy your holidays!
>   You, too!

However, it could refer to either one. Sometimes the context will make it more obvious where the "as well" should be applied:

> Are you ready to order your food now?
>   Yes. I would like to order a potato and a salad as well.

Compare that exchange with:

> Are you ready to order your food now?
>   Yes, I am, and my friend is as well.

In those two examples, the first "as well" refers to the verb in the reply, while the second "as well" refers to the verb in the initial question.